# How to connect to Testnet on Blockfrost API with blockfrost-js

Tags: blockfrost

I am getting an error connecting to the Blockfrost API with blockfrost-js

> "Network token mismatch. Are you using token for the correct network?
> See [https://docs.blockfrost.io/#section/Available-networks."](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#section/Available-networks.%22)

I went to blockfrost.io and requested a API key for the testnet, but I still have this error. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to the Testnet with blockfrost-js initialize it like this:

```
const API = new BlockFrostAPI({
  projectId: 'YOURAPIKEYFORTESTNET',
  isTestnet: true
});
```